# Can I add more after "this" in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I'm working on a script that fades in and out both an image and a div I have set behind the image when you hover over the image. I'm having two problems:

1. The fades on the image and div don't seem to move at the same speed even though I have them set to.
2. I can't figure out how to get the div's to only show for the image you hover over. If I could type ("this" div.info) as an object, it would work fine. Is there a way to do that?

I can't get `$(".info",this)`, `$(this).find(".info")`, or `$(".info", $(this).closest("li"))` to work.

---

**Result:** I have found the solution. I was able to get it to work by using lthibodeaux's suggestion and using `$(".info", $(this).closest("li"))` as the object and making all the functions `.fadeTo` go here for the result: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Z5p4K/7/

Edit:

- I found out the image and the div animations really were moving at the same speed, just the image only had it's z-index set on hover, so if you took your mouse off the image while the animation was running, it would appear to move at a different speed than the div when really the image was behind the div, it only appeared to be moving at different speeds because when the div became invisible you could see the image behind it but when it became opaque, the image was gone (making you think the image became invisible when really the div was in front of the image). This was easily fixed by moving the the z-index property from `ul.columns li:hover img` to `ul.columns li img`.
- The div only had a border around it while you hovered over it. This was easily fixed by changing the border properties from `ul.columns li:hover .info` to `ul.columns li .info`

Check out the final version here: http://jsfiddle.net/tV9Bw/

This is the final version because I can no longer find any problems with any of the code; everything is optimized, there are no glitches, and it looks great.

Thanks to everyone who answered and to Yi Jiang for editing this post with better formatting. I'm new to this site so I wasn't sure how to properly format my question.

and a Huge thanks to artyom.stv for fixing the last glitch in the script that I didn't know how to fix.

Comment: Your code have a common bug: If you move mouse from one image to another and back again several times then images begin blinking (because fade-ins and fade-outs are queued).

Comment: They don't blink, they queue up and run through the animations as they should one after another. I am aware of this, however I don't want to fix it. Because the only way to prevent that is to stop the animation on mouseout instead of fading out on mouseout, which would mean a huge aesthetic drop (at least for me, I think the fadeout is what makes it look really good). So since this bug can't actually cause any problems, fixing it would be worse than keeping it.

Comment: Here I have done some work for you: http://jsfiddle.net/tV9Bw/. That is what I meant. It was easier to explain the idea in the code `:)`

Comment: Wow, very nice work; I never could've done that myself. Thank you very much, I gave your comment an upvote.

Comment: Oh, what difference does that make?

Comment: Sorry. I removed that comment `:)`. My code was a little bit more complicated and had an error. While in jsfiddle.net/tV9Bw there is no one. I've too hurried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the general idea. One thing you should know about a selector is that you are able to define a second argument as the scope of the selector, i.e.

```
$("selectorString", scopeObject)
```

In your case, make the second argument `$(this).closest("li")`. It will find the list item containing your image and select `.info` descendants of that container:

```
$(".info", $(this).closest("li")).fadeIn(1000);
```

Comment: This is the only suggested one that I was able to get to work. Thank you very much, I posted the finished product in the edited OP. (it's the jsfiddle) If I had 15 reputation I'd give you an up vote =p

Answer (score 1):

Change `$(".info")` to `$(this).find(".info")` and all will be sweet.

Comment: Okay thank you so very much, I knew what I wanted, I just had no idea what the syntax was

Comment: @Mark I recommend `$( '.info', this )`

Comment: What is the advantage, besides less characters?

Comment: @bundy There is none (besides that).

Comment: I can't get either of those syntax's to work. If you can get it to work, please show me in the jsfiddle, that's why I posted it in the OP. Thanks -Mark

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use something like `$(this).find(".info")` as mentioned by Bundy

but as *The jQuery constructor accepts a 2nd parameter which can be used to override the context of the selection.*
You can also do something like this:

```
$(".info",this)
```

Comment: Why is it better to do it like that? It gets translated internally to the former anyway.

Comment: @alex: Check [this](http://jsperf.com/find-vs-descendant-selector/13) out,  restricting the context works faster then `.find()`

Comment: @alex Not having to write "find" is not better?

Comment: I can't get either of those syntax's to work. If you can get it to work, please show me in the jsfiddle, that's why I posted it in the OP. Thanks -Mark

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: I find it more clearer to write `find()` as it reads better to me. Works the same though, so it's up to you.

Comment: @OmeidHerat: Do you wish to provide evidence or cite a resource as to how they don't work the same?

Comment: @alex But `$( selector, context )` is such a beautiful notation, and `$( context ).find( selector )` is so long, and ... ah, never mind `:P`

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Maybe like `$(fn)` vs `$(document).ready(fn)`, I'll learn to love the terser version :)

Comment: @OmeidHerat From the jQuery source code: `// HANDLE: $(expr, context) // (which is just equivalent to: $(context).find(expr)`. They work the same.

Comment: @Šime I updated the jsperf test to the latest jQuery - http://jsperf.com/find-vs-descendant-selector/18 - in Chrome the former is clearly faster.

Comment: @Alnitak `$('#container').find('div.robotarm');` is slightly faster than `$('div.robotarm', "#container");`, **as expected**. The options "context" and "context2" are not comparable to the other options. They could be compared to `$(container).find('div.robotarm');` but such an option is not present. I made a [proper test here](http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-context-vs-jquery-context-find-selector) - `find()` is slightly faster, again **as expected**. The reasoning behind this is that `$(selector, context)` is internally transformed to `$(context).find(selector)`.

Comment: @Alnitak Btw the performance difference is of course insignificant in real-world applications, and I recommend `$( selector, context )` because of its smaller and terser notation.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas yes, you're right, of course.  I overlooked that the original jsperf used a pre-evaluated context in some cases, but not others.