# Problem in show value jQuery toolti

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a tooltip and i have problem with it, i want:

When that `mouseenter` on `hi` show value into next div it `value hi` 
When that `mouseenter` on `hello` show value into next div it `value hello`

But in following code, when that `mouseenter` on each tow `hi` & `hello` showing `value hello`,

How can fix it?

```
var tip = $('.tool_tip').closest('li').find('div').clone();
$('.tool_tip').mouseenter(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
    $div = '.'+$this.closest('li').find('div').attr('class');
    $(this).attr('title', '');
    $($div).hide().fadeIn('slow').children('.tipBody').html(tip);
}).mousemove(function (e) {

    $('.tooltip').css('top', e.pageY + 10);
    $('.tooltip').css('left', e.pageX + 20);

}).mouseleave(function () {
    $('.tooltip').hide();
})
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/dege4/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var tip = $('.tool_tip').closest('li').find('div').clone();
$('.tool_tip').mouseenter(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
    $div = $this.closest('li').find('div');
    $(this).attr('title', '');
    $div.hide().fadeIn('slow');
}).mousemove(function (e) {

    $('.tooltip').css('top', e.pageY + 10);
    $('.tooltip').css('left', e.pageX + 20);

}).mouseleave(function () {
    $('.tooltip').hide();
})
```

works @ http://jsfiddle.net/dege4/5/

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem here: [Can I add more after "this" in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508706/can-i-add-more-after-this-in-javascript).

When referencing the parent `li` of your tooltip try using this code: `$(".tooltip", $(this).closest("li"))`